# Could not create a share with SAP UI5 Repository

Tags: eclipse, repository, sapui5

I'd like to share my SAPUI5 project to my ABAP Backend.
But I can't connect to the backend.
Ii I right-click on the project -> Team -> Share Project... I can see the Popup. Then I choose SAPUI5 ABAP Repository and click next. **Nothing happens!**
Sometimes I've got error "Null pointer exception", but sometimes it does nothing.

Please have a look at the logfile.
Does anyone know a workaround ? How can I create a share manually?

Kind regards - Sven

---

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2020-06-03 07:22:22.227
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sap.ide.ui5.team.ui.internal.AfrRepositoryProviderConfigurationWizard$5.invoke(AfrRepositoryProviderConfigurationWizard.java:409)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.canSupportCTSProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.sap.adt.transport.ui.internal.widgets.TransportSelectionComposite.isCTSProjectSupported(TransportSelectionComposite.java:1264)
    at com.sap.adt.transport.ui.internal.widgets.TransportSelectionComposite.createControl(TransportSelectionComposite.java:1215)
    at com.sap.adt.transport.ui.internal.widgets.TransportSelectionComposite.<init>(TransportSelectionComposite.java:177)
    at com.sap.adt.transport.ui.internal.widgets.TransportSelectionWizardPage$1.<init>(TransportSelectionWizardPage.java:81)
    at com.sap.adt.transport.ui.internal.widgets.TransportSelectionWizardPage.createControl(TransportSelectionWizardPage.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
    at com.sap.ide.ui5.team.ui.internal.AfrRepositoryProviderConfigurationWizard.createPageControls(AfrRepositoryProviderConfigurationWizard.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1234)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$$Lambda$612/155678765.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage.lambda$1(ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage$$Lambda$597/1616936875.doubleClick(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$$Lambda$20/1422262786.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDoubleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4024)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3624)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizard.openWizard(ConfigureProjectWizard.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizard.shareProjects(ConfigureProjectWizard.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.ConfigureProjectAction.lambda$0(ConfigureProjectAction.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.ConfigureProjectAction$$Lambda$575/1253482877.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.lambda$1(TeamAction.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction$$Lambda$576/137209289.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.run(TeamAction.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.ConfigureProjectAction.execute(ConfigureProjectAction.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.run(TeamAction.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.runWithEvent(TeamAction.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$$Lambda$287/1231956957.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4024)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3624)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$32/451801229.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

Comment: Is not using Eclipse an option? SAP stopped development on the Eclipse extension so it's basically deprecated.

Comment: no, it's not an option. Why stopped SAP the development? Last ADT-Version ist 2020-03... I don't think it has stopped.

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/11/26/sapui5-tools-for-eclipse-now-is-the-time-to-look-for-alternatives/ > `we have decided to retire the SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse`. ADT !== UI5

Comment: Thank you. It seems, this is the cause of the error... :(

Comment: If this really is the error you could downgrade your Eclipse and ADT to 2019-12.